# Unity StandAlone GetAxis() doesn't work if I hold 2 buttons on external keyboard

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine, user-input

I work with standard Input.GetAxis("horizontal") and some Input.GetKeyDown on simple Update() loop.

All work on standard keyboard of my mac book pro.

Connecting a external usb keyboard to a mac book pro, and hold both "B" and "V" the Left Arrow is not detected and the axis "horizontal" doesn't work.

Also, if I hold "B" and Left Arrow the "V" key is not detected.

Any idea for a workaround?

Use this code to replicate

```css
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TestKey : MonoBehaviour {


 string inputState;

 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update () 
 {
  inputState = string.Format(
   "\nAxis:{0}\nB:{1}\nV:{2}"
   ,Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")
   ,Input.GetKey(KeyCode.B)
   ,Input.GetKey(KeyCode.V)
   );
 }


 void OnGUI()
 {
  GUI.Label(new Rect(0,0,Screen.width,Screen.height),inputState);
 }

}
```

Comment: Post your code so we can be sure there isn't a flaw in your code.

Comment: Look up to see the sample code to replicate the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have an error in your code pleas, post your code ,, did you change in the GetAxis ?.. Becouse your update loop may stop when you click on another key and not moveing on to the next part of the loop.. Try to look here

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[System.Serializable]
public class Boundary
{
    public float xMin, xMax, zMin, zMax;
}

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    public float tilt;
    public Boundary boundary;

    void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");

        Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);
        rigidbody.velocity = movement * speed;

        rigidbody.position = new Vector3 
        (
            Mathf.Clamp (rigidbody.position.x, boundary.xMin, boundary.xMax), 
            0.0f, 
            Mathf.Clamp (rigidbody.position.z, boundary.zMin, boundary.zMax)
        );

        rigidbody.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (0.0f, 0.0f, rigidbody.velocity.x * -tilt);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found that is not Unity related issue: is a hardware limitation of apple keyboard that doesn't track multiple key simultaneously.

I connect another high-end keyboard (called N-Key rollover) and all work fine.

Use this link to some reference about rollover capability:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_(key)

Comment: That would have been my 2nd suggestion but I thought this is a problem of the past. Apparently not, good to know.